# How ST_Within/ST_Contains works with geo data?

Tags: algorithm, postgresql, gis, geospatial, postgis

The question: what algorithm/or algorithm**s** uses [spatial databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_database) to check that geo point (latitude and longitude) belong to "geo rect" (4 geo points connected by meridians and parallels)?

At first I thought that it is simple projection plus algorithms for
2-D plane indexing, like r-tree, but
how then these databases dealing with points near south/north pole and/or -180 and 180 longitude.

For example lets our point is `(0, E 180)`, and the rectangle is `(N 1, W 179), (N 1, E 179), (S 1, E 179), (S 1, E 179)`,

where N = north, E = east, W = west, S = south.

If map rectangle to [Mercator](http://www.dmap.co.uk/ll2tm.htm) then we got:

(-126799830, 5434036), 
(139214148, 6832332),
(-126799830, -16488164)
(139214148, -17886459),

and our point is (142452996, -5527064).

And in such projection point not belong to rectangle,
while it actually belong.

Actually no one projection can helps with such case, because of it should
map geo point to several different locations, to handle cases when
rectangle cross E 180, W 180, N 90, S 90 and when rectangle not cross such boundaries.

So how spatial databases check that geo point belongs  to geo rect?

Comment: By projecting: http://proj4.org/faq.html (for instance)

Comment: @wildplasser But what exactly kind of projection used in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the postgis source code, the "within" calculation for geographic types is done calculating the distance between objects.

Here's the geography_dwtithin function, that is called by st_dwithin https://github.com/gravitystorm/postgis/blob/master/postgis/geography_measurement.c#L107

Then lwgeom_distance_spheroid http://postgis.net/docs/doxygen/2.1/da/de7/liblwgeom_8h_a2aac0f91b6dfd27873ab828a1874805b.html that compares bboxes before measuring distance.

The distance calculation can be found here
http://postgis.net/docs/doxygen/2.1/d2/ddd/lwgeodetic_8c_a56339ad4a240527a078249dc8e56b082.html#a56339ad4a240527a078249dc8e56b082

At rows 1756 - 1764 you can find the calculation for the simplest case (point to point). The other cases uses the same logic, but looking for the nearest points.

Then you can find the sphere_distance calculation here
http://postgis.net/docs/doxygen/2.1/d2/ddd/lwgeodetic_8c_ab9f003c831c66b723beca7103e811785.html#ab9f003c831c66b723beca7103e811785

and the spheroid_distance calculation here
http://postgis.net/docs/doxygen/2.1/d0/d7a/lwgeodetic_8h_a5c2565cd7f88783c32b777ca58d4dbcc.html#a5c2565cd7f88783c32b777ca58d4dbcc

Comment: If so, then what sense in postgis at all? If you have one point and `10000` rects, than you have to do `10000 * 4` distance calculations, so it is database without indexes, because of linearly depend on size of dataset, so postgis is useless database?

Comment: Indexes are evaluated before that calculation.

Comment: If indexes took part in calculation, then then indexing algorithm is part of what I am asking for.

Comment: In fact reference to `ptarray_distance_spheroid` not answer to anything, because of  ok, we calc distance, between for example 4 points of rect and testing point, and what next, how we can answer point inside rect or not?

Comment: I've edited the answer with the parts before the distance calculation

Comment: Big thanks, but `ST_Within` take only two values, where  `tolerance` come from?

Answer (score 0):

In PostGIS there are difference between geometry and geography.

Take a look at their [documentation](https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#PostGIS_Geography):

> The basis for the PostGIS geometry type is a plane. The shortest path
>   between two points on the plane is a straight line. That means
>   calculations on geometries (areas, distances, lengths, intersections,
>   etc) can be calculated using cartesian mathematics and straight line
>   vectors.
>
> The basis for the PostGIS geographic type is a sphere. The shortest
>   path between two points on the sphere is a great circle arc. **That
>   means that calculations on geographies (areas, distances, lengths,
>   intersections, etc) must be calculated on the sphere, using more
>   complicated mathematics.**

Mercator is geometry based projection. Use geographic projection WGS-84 if you need to work with lat-lon coordinates.

Comment: Sorry for misundertanding, in fact question about what kind of `using more complicated mathematics` postgis use in this case